# Starting services in a specific order on Red Hat?

Tags: rhel, boot, systemd

I have a couple of services using "ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar" and I want them to start as late as possible (after network, firewall and login service).

I have tried to list different dependencies in [Unit] both "After" and "Requires", but it doesn't seems to do anything. If I look at the boot log my services starts before all dependencies.

I've tried (for example),

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service 01
Requires=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service network.target
```

I can see that crond starts last in the boot sequence, so I've tried.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service 02
After=crond.service
```

No difference... My services starts long before crond.

Any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong? It's the same on both Red Hat 7.2 and 7.3.

Comment: What does your `[Install]` section look like?

Answer (score -1):

The [Arch wiki sysyemd page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Handling_dependencies) has a bit of insight into this:

> Note that Wants= and Requires= do not imply After=, meaning that if After= is not specified, the two units will be started in parallel.

For each dependency, you probably want to add *both* a `Requires` and `After` for each unit that you want it to start after:

```
[Unit] 
Description=My Service 02 
Requires=crond.service
After=crond.service
```

Comment: The asker already has `After` in their service file. Unless their service actually requires cron (or whatever they're starting after), they should not be making it required.

Comment: Good point, you're right that this includes a possibly unnecessary ```Requires```, perhaps I'll have to rethink my answer.